# display Table structure of multiple mysql tables

Tags: mysql

I am trying to display table structures of multiple mysql tables(like list of columns per table) which matches particular string like

`SHOW CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%CATEGORY%'`

I did this but it does not show structure of the table.

```
`select * from `information_schema`.`tables`
  where table_name like 'category%' AND TABLE_SCHEMA =  'DB_name'`
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To get the full structure of the table, you'd need to query many tables in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA, not just TABLES. The TABLES contains only attributes of the table, not of its columns, indexes, or constraints.

There is no INFORMATION_SCHEMA table that shows the full `CREATE TABLE` statement like `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

`SHOW CREATE TABLE` accepts only one table name as an argument.

The easiest solution would be to get a list of the tables that match your pattern:

```
select table_name from `information_schema`.`tables`
where table_name like 'category%' AND TABLE_SCHEMA =  'DB_name'
```

And then fetch the results of that query in a loop, and run `SHOW CREATE TABLE DBName.<table_name>` for each table returned by the query.

Comment: The problem with this is I have a lot of tables which has that name that is why i was looking for any method maybe a loop which can display this result at one go. Something like `WhileLoop() BEGIN DECLARE table_name  VARCHAR(100); SET table_name = 'category' ;                              
WHILE    table_name LIKE 'category%' DO 'Get Table names and '   END WHILE;`

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I'm referring to -- a loop. Perhaps you would like to learn to write some code to do that. You could use a MySQL stored procedure, or literally any other programming language. Up to you.